# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' when using LGBMClassifier wrapper

Tags: python, pandas, lightgbm

I'm trying to use sklearn wrapper LGBMClassifier class in python. Shapes and types of datasets:

```
print(type(train_x))
train_x.shape
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(3125, 18)

```
print(type(train_y))
train_y.shape
```

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
(3125,)

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier

lgbm_wrapper = LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=400, learning_rate=0.1, random_state=123)
lgbm_wrapper.fit(train_x, train_y, verbose=True, eval_metric="logloss")
```

It gives me an attribute error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-74f8c97dd31f> in <module>()
      2 
      3 lgbm_wrapper = LGBMClassifier()
----> 4 lgbm_wrapper.fit(train_x, train_y, verbose=True, eval_metric="logloss")

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in c_str(string)
    110 def c_str(string):
    111     """Convert a Python string to C string."""
--> 112     return ctypes.c_char_p(string.encode('utf-8'))
    113 
    114 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What does this mean? I'm running this in a Google colab documentation, but should I install other utilities to get my work done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the dtypes of the pandas dataframe

```
train_x.dtypes
train_y.dtypes
```

I have a feeling one of the features in your dataframe is a tuple?

Comment: train_x.dtypes - dtype: object(all 18 columns consist of 'float64') and train_y.dtypes - dtype('int64') How can I figure out which one belongs to tuple?

Comment: If train_x.dtypes is giving you object, that means some of the values are not float64.

Comment: `import numpy as np` and then try running this command: `train_x[~train_x.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)]`. This will list any rows which has any non-numeric value.